# How would Kant/Mill justify causing somebody discomfort when doing the righteous thing?

Tags: ethics, kant, metaethics, deontology, john-stuart-mill

I was wondering how Kant, or even Mill might respond to the issue that when doing the righteous thing, say standing up for yourself against a bully, or somebody who wants to impede on your rights, you cause said person discomfort.

> The only purpose for which power can be rightfully exercised over any
> member of a civilized community, against his will, is to prevent harm
> to others. **His own good, either physical or moral, is not sufficient
> warrant.**

As for Mill the above passage seems to preclude standing up for what is right if it causes harm.

Comment: But a bully does cause harm, and standing up to him does prevent it.  Even if the person harmed  is yourself, you are an other person relative to him.

Comment: On Liberty, which you quote, is concerned with exercising *government* power. Moreover, the very next sentence says: "*He cannot rightfully be compelled to do or forbear because it will be better for him to do so, because it will make him happier*". In other words, this has nothing to do with self-defense, which he endorses in the previous sentence:"*the sole end for which mankind are warranted, individually or collectively, in interfering with the liberty of action of any of their number, is self-protection.*" And it is best not to mix Kant with Mill, their ethical principles are incompatible